# Confusion in constraint equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, constrained-dynamics

[image: (Sorry for bad drawing.)]

I have to find the relation between $a$ and $b$ using constraint equation of the string.
(Note: a and b are accelerations.)
(Note: Friction is to be ignored, string and pulley is ideal and all surfaces are smooth. The 2 blocks are akways in contact.)
The book says that the correct answer is $a=b$.
However I am getting $a(1+cos\theta)=b$.
Am I doing something wrong in considering the component of acceleration a along the plane?

Comment: What is a and what is b? Accelerations? Forces?

Comment: @AndreiZ. accelerations forgot to mention that my bad.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Sketch]

Consider your $b$ to be along the $r$ coordinate and your $a$ along the x coordinate as depicted in the figure. For every $\Delta x$ that the big block moves to the right, the small block gains this $\Delta x$ in the $r$ coordinate. If you consider the initial position to be as in the picture $x=0$ when $r=0$ (even with an initial displacement in r the accelerations in the end will still hold) then:

\begin{equation}
x(t)=r(t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=\dot{r}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}=\ddot{r}
\end{equation}